# Novice d3 stacked area graph

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

Many apologies for a probably simple Q.
I've looked at the example page here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885211# I've then modified the line:

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
```

to be

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
```

To point to a datafile with contents:

```
date,Kermit,piggy,Gonzo,fuzzy,hogthrob,animal,floyd,Gabriel,Beaker,scooter,statler,waldorf,slim,sam
13-Oct-31,113.44,435.15,19.57,60.55,53.02,268.28,87.34,1.98,0,31.68,0,21.59,4.82,11.31
13-Nov-30,109.86,506.85,18.97,58.77,388.37,131.48,85.34,1.98,0,48.50,0,21.59,4.70,11.31
13-Dec-31,113.46,644.88,19.57,60.57,669.47,0,87.46,1.98,0,80.97,0,21.59,4.82,11.43
```

On refreshing the browser the x axis and dates appear correct BUT only a single data point (for Kermit) is plotted as though is were the only bar on the chart.

Could someone point me in the right direction. As a complete d3 novice any assitance would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, looks like that should work. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Sadly not, the console looks clean (objects all look sane) and using python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 shows all accesses are 200. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that each row in the data in the [Stacked Area Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885211#) sums to 100. Your data, however, sums to different values in each row, and the value of `'Kermit'` is `>100` for each date. As a result, while D3 is drawing all the paths for your dataset, they are not within the bounds of graph.

To fix this issue, you need to initialize the `domain` of your y-axis so it is not expecting your values to be in the range of `[1, 100]` by default. You can add the following after initializing the x-axis domain:

```
// Find the value of the day with highest total value
var maxDateVal = d3.max(data, function(d){
  var vals = d3.keys(d).map(function(key){ return key !== "date" ? d[key] : 0 });
  return d3.sum(vals);
});

// Set domains for axes
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, maxDateVal])
```

The only other change you need to make is to stop normalizing your data by making this change

```
return {date: d.date, y: d[name] * 1}; /// 100};
```

and commenting out the lines that format the text on your y-axis as percentages:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%y-%b-%d").parse;
    //formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");
.
.
.
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    //.tickFormat(formatPercent);
```

See a full example at this [bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/mdml/8305340).

Making these changes, I get the following graph:
[image]

Comment: That's much closer, many thanks. Now to set the domain to take into account the full stacked data range.

Comment: @B0D: I thought about it a bit more and I figured out the scaling issue. Please check out the updated answer and [bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/mdml/8305340).